# how to read Collection of Collections element in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have made collection named AllCollection and assigned data from range in sheet "All". Now I'm trying to compare value in collection (i) and element (i,1), however I can't figure out correct syntax. I have tried countless forms, like AllCollection(i)(i, 1) or AllCollection(i(i, 1)) without luck. I'm not using arrays, because I dont know sizes of OP3Collection and NewCollection.

```
Dim OP3Collection As New Collection
Dim NewCollection As New Collection
Dim AllCollection As New Collection
...
some other code
...
AllCollection.Add Sheets("All").Range("A2:AL" & LastRow).Value
LastRowC = 0
For i = 1 To LastRow - 1
    If AllCollection.Item1(i).Items1(i, 1) = "*" Then
        NewCollection.Add AllCollection.Item(i)
    ElseIf AllCollection.Item1(i).Items1(i, 1) = 3 Then
        OP3Collection.Add AllCollection.Item(i)
    End If
    Str = "Split: Copying data from sheet /All/ to sheets /New/,/OldPop3/ "
    Call ProgressOfCode(i, LastRow - 1, Str)
    Str = ""
Next
LastRowC = NewCollection.Count
Sheets("New").Range("A2:AL" & LastRowC + 1).Value = NewCollection
LastRowC = OP3Collection.Count
Sheets("OldPop3").Range("A2:AL" & LastRowC + 1).Value = OP3Collection
...
```

Comment: It will be the same as you are accessing them to put them in, you are adding the collection item, not the collection, so you are saying bucket 1 is split into 2 buckets.  `op3collection.add allcollection` would be a collection of collections.  So you would say `NewCollection.Item(x)` what

Comment: AllCollection.Add Sheets("All").Range("A2:AL" & LastRow).Value line adds something like AllCollection -> Items 1 (1) .... -> Items (1,1) .... Items (i,1), where Items 1(1) is equal to row in table, and I want to access first cell of that row,

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A2:AL" & LastRow).Value` gives you a 2-dimensional array with all the values you have in the cells of the range.

So when you write `AllCollection.Add Sheets("All").Range("A2:AL" & LastRow).Value`, you are adding a new item into the collection, holding a 2-dimensional array.

This stays true when you add one of the items from one collection to the second: `NewCollection.Add AllCollection.Item(i)` will put an d-dimensional array into ? 
`NewCollection` - but be carefull, it is *the same* array, not a copy.

You access the single items of the array with
`AllCollection(1)(1,1)` or (maybe easier to read) `AllCollection.item(1)(1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wonders about similar problem I wrote different code with arrays, that is much faster.

```
NewArray = Sheets("All").Range("A2:AL" & LastRow).Value
OP3Array = Sheets("All").Range("A2:AL" & LastRow).Value
For i = 1 To LastRow - 1
    If NewArray(i, 1) <> "*" Then
        For j = 1 To 38
            NewArray(i, j) = Empty
        Next
    End If
    If OP3Array(i, 1) <> 3 Then
        For j = 1 To 38
            OP3Array(i, j) = Empty
        Next
    End If
    Str = "Split: Copying data from sheet /All/ to sheets /New/,/OldPop3/ "
    Call ProgressOfCode(i, LastRow - 1, Str)
    Str = ""
Next

ArraySize = UBound(NewArray)
Sheets("New").Range("A2:AL" & ArraySize + 1).Value = NewArray
'Sorts and pushes empty rows to bottom
Sheets("New").Range("A2:AL" & ArraySize + 1).Sort 
Key1:=Sheets("New").Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

ArraySize = UBound(OP3Array)
Sheets("OldPop3").Range("A2:AL" & ArraySize + 1).Value = OP3Array
'Sorts and pushes empty rows to bottom
Sheets("OldPop3").Range("A2:AL" & ArraySize + 1).Sort 
Key1:=Sheets("OldPop3").Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
```